# Using sub item in ListView Android

Tags: android, android-listview

I make asset management system information project, and save the data in `SQLite database`. I want to show the information and time in the `listview`, but it just show the information. I want both to show up in the `listview`. Any ideas how to do it ?

The string for the information is `daftar` and the time is `timer`.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" > 


        <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" >
        </ListView>   

</LinearLayout>
```

Here's my database.java

```
public class Database extends Activity {
 String[] daftar,timer; 
 ListView ListView01;
 Menu menu;
 protected Cursor cursor,cursor2;
 DataCenter dbcenter;
 public static Database ma;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.database);


  ma = this;
        dbcenter = new DataCenter(this);
        RefreshList();
 }

 public void RefreshList(){
     SQLiteDatabase db = dbcenter.getReadableDatabase();
     cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM data",null);
     cursor2 = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM data",null);

     timer = new String[cursor2.getCount()];
     daftar = new String[cursor.getCount()];

     cursor.moveToFirst();
     for (int cc=0; cc < cursor.getCount(); cc++){
      cursor.moveToPosition(cc);
      daftar[cc] = cursor.getString(1).toString();
     }

     cursor2.moveToNext();
     for (int bb=0; bb < cursor2.getCount(); bb++){
      cursor2.moveToPosition(bb);
      timer[bb] = cursor2.getString(3).toString();
     }



     ListView01 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
     ListView01.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, daftar));
     ListView01.setSelected(true);
     ListView01.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
       final String selection = daftar[arg2]; //.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();
       final CharSequence[] dialogitem = {"View", "Edit", "Delete"};
       AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Database.this);
       builder.setTitle("Pilih Menu");
       builder.setItems(dialogitem, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
         switch(item){
         case 0 :
          Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DetailDatabase.class);
          i.putExtra("informasi", selection);
          startActivity(i);
          break;
         case 1 :
          Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UbahDatabase.class);
          in.putExtra("informasi", selection);
          startActivity(in);
          break;
         case 2 :
          SQLiteDatabase db = dbcenter.getWritableDatabase();
          db.execSQL("delete from data where informasi = '"+selection+"'");
          RefreshList();
          break;
         }
        }
       });
       builder.create().show();
      }});
      ((ArrayAdapter)ListView01.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetInvalidated();
     }

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
  return true;
 }

}
```

Comment: you need to use a custom adapter for listview

Comment: @AttiqurRehman can you please write the code ? I dont know how to make it

Comment: Okay, Give me some time to see. what can I write

Comment: @AttiqurRehman I will wait.

Comment: I edited my answer, check your referenced code

Comment: @AttiqurRehman it doesnt work. the "daftar" and "timer" connected to SQLite Database where I take the information and time. But, thanks for helping me.

Comment: How do you suggest we make it work? From your question, I concluded that you want to show two rows in the listview. As far as, Data from SQLite is concerned, it is different query

Comment: @AttiqurRehman I want to use the sub item where the data I get is from SQLite database, I already get the answer and it's work. You can download my project to see it https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GINi8sg9uh-8P4A2RQDyGkrADKCkZUmd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally get the answer, thanks for helping me. I know the code is still in messed up, but it works. Thanks for everyone who helping me. I make the CRUD project based SQLite Database and the listview show the subitem from the database. You can download the project 
[HERE](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GINi8sg9uh-8P4A2RQDyGkrADKCkZUmd)

```
public void RefreshList(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbcenter.getReadableDatabase();

        cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM biodata",null);

        daftar = new String[cursor.getCount()];
        timer = new String[cursor.getCount()];

        ArrayList<Map<String,Object>> itemDataList = new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();;

        cursor.moveToFirst();

        for (int cc=0; cc < cursor.getCount(); cc++){
            cursor.moveToPosition(cc);
            daftar[cc] = cursor.getString(1).toString();
            timer[cc] = cursor.getString(3).toString();

            String[] daftarr = daftar;
            String[] timerr = timer;

            Map<String,Object> listItemMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();
            listItemMap.put("title", daftarr[cc]);
            listItemMap.put("description", timerr[cc]);
            itemDataList.add(listItemMap);


        ListView01 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this,itemDataList,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
                new String[]{"title","description"},new int[]{android.R.id.text1,android.R.id.text2});

        ListView01.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);


         ListView01.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
               final String selection = daftar[arg2]; //.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();
               final CharSequence[] dialogitem = {"View", "Edit", "Delete"};
               AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
               builder.setTitle("Pilih Menu");
               builder.setItems(dialogitem, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                 switch(item){
                 case 0 :
                  Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LihatActivity.class);
                  i.putExtra("nama", selection);
                  startActivity(i);
                  break;
                 case 1 :
                  Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UbahActivity.class);
                  in.putExtra("nama", selection);
                  startActivity(in);
                  break;
                 case 2 :
                  SQLiteDatabase db = dbcenter.getWritableDatabase();
                  db.execSQL("delete from biodata where nama = '"+selection+"'");
                  RefreshList();
                  break;
                 }
                }
               });
               builder.create().show();
              }});
              ((SimpleAdapter)ListView01.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        }
             }
```

For everyone who helping me, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I made changes in your RefreshList function. Just removed your SQLite data and replaced with local data). Check the image for reference
[image]

```
 public void RefreshList(){
        timer = new String[6];
        daftar = new String[6];
        for (int cc=0; cc < daftar.length; cc++)
            daftar[cc] = "daftar " + cc;
        for (int bb=0; bb < timer.length; bb++)
            timer[bb] = "timer "+bb;

    ListView01 = findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> listArg = new ArrayList<>();
    HashMap<String, Object> map;
    for(int i=0; i<timer.length; i++){
        map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("timer", timer[i]);
        map.put("daftar", daftar[i]);
        listArg.add(map);
    }

    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, listArg, R.layout.row, new String[]{"timer", "daftar"}, new int[]{R.id.tvTimer, R.id.tvDaftar});
    ListView01.setAdapter(adapter);
    ListView01.setSelected(true);
}
```

You need to use a simple or custom adapter Because your current adapter **ArrayAdapter** could only handle one string at a time.

For tutorials check this links [Link 1](https://www.journaldev.com/10416/android-listview-with-custom-adapter-example-tutorial) or [Link 2](https://www.devglan.com/android/create-custom-adapter-in-list-view)

Comment: please, can you write the code ? I still dont understand.

Comment: @MuhammadHaries Welcome in programming word (: